# iterate through a string until the exact value is in the dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary-comprehension

I am trying to decode a binary string using a dictionary with these keys and values

data =  "1001011101100100001000100000010011000000000100"

sdict = {"100":"h", "101":"e", "110":"l", "0100":"o","00100":"w","0000100":"r","00000000100":"d"}

This is what I have tried so far:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
if data[i] in sdict.keys():
    decoded += sdict[data[i]]
else:
    decoded += data[i]
```

[It gives me this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfGfr.png)

The decoded message should be helloworld

Comment: what is `fres` referring to

Comment: sorry I used the wrong variable, it should be data, should be fixed by now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are comparing each character to to strings of multiple characters.  That is what the `history` variable is for in my example below.  It collects each character until it reaches a point where the full string matches a key in the dictionary.

You can try this:

```
decoded = ""   
history = ""  # all characters visited since last key was found
for i in data:
    history += i                     #  add each character to history
    if history in sdict:             # if history is a key in dictionary
        decoded += sdict[history]    # add key's value to decoded
        history = ""                 # reset history
```

output = `helloworld`